# Show an (custom) error when "required" runtime libraries are not present?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, dependencies

I've been making a program in Visual Studio 2012, what comes with it is that when I send my application to someone, they need the VS2012 Runtime, which sometimes they don't know where to download or what they need (for normal users "xxx.dll is missing" is very misleading).

I know exactly which dependencies my application requires (fantom.dll [Lego Mindstorms stuff] and the VC++ 2012 Redist).

I would like to show a dialog when these libraries are missing on application startup and provide the user with download links for these libraries.

Is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: Can't you provide the required redist and dlls with your program?

Comment: a 30kb program should include 30MB of runtime files? :P is there really no other way than including them or a readme.txt ? XD

Comment: So you're suggesting the user downloads the 30Mb runtime files? How's that different from you providing it for them, especially if it's not something that's likely to be on their machine, such as the Mindstorm dll.

Comment: some users already have the libraries, so why add and extra 30 mb to the package :F

Comment: That's a fair point; who is your target audience and how are you sending them the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you could do something like:

1. Move all of the code in your binary into a DLL.
2. Create an EXE which dynamically loads the DLL using LoadLibrary and unloads it with FreeLibrary.
3. If LoadLibrary fails, check if its due to missing DLLs, if so then display a MessageBox/your custom message and exit.

Of course this means your EXE project must NOT depend on the runtime itself - this shouldn't be an issue since you'll only need to call 3 win32 API's.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible but you can create an installer for your program. The error is thrown during the loading of your program, before your code execution...

You can try with that : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24187/Creating-an-Installer

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for testing the VS2012 Runtime dynamically, but you can certainly validate fantom.dll dynamically.  Instead of static-linking to the DLL directly, you can dynamically load it instead.  You can configure your project to delay-load the DLL at run-time, and then provide a delay-load callback handler that the RTL will call if the delay-load fails.  Or you can simply skip the delay-load feature and load the DLL yourself manually by calling `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` directly.

Comment: yeah that's true for that dll

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can verify if a dependency exists on the deployed system.  A few things come to mind...

- You can see if the assembly is recognized on the running system by calling  `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve()` .  [Further reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)
- Another more primitive option is to call a `File.Exists(your assembly path here)` test, but I would advise against this as it's a bad practice to require hard-pathed installation locations.

That said, and as others have stated, it's still *by far* the best approach to create yourself an installation distribution.

Comment: I don't think this will be of much use, the tags suggest C++ app so requiring .NET as well isn't likely to help :)

Comment: Whoopsie!  Stumbled over this through the Windows-tagged group and saw C++ as C#.  Clumsy me. ;)